# Logging into OS X Server in a DMZ form a Mac Client

Tags: osx-server

I have a Mac OS X Server (10.8.3) that is in a DMZ. It has a domain name and an external and internal IP. When I am not on my network I can see the server when I open up Server.app on my client computer (for example when I have Wi-Fi on). But when I am logged into the network, I cannot see the server when I try to use Server.app, and nothing I enter allows me to connect to it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Bryan

Comment: Are you using IP or domain name in your Server.app?

Comment: I believe we are using the domain name. That is what it says in the "Network" tab of the Server.App application.